# перебор одного конкретного свойства множества объектов внутри массива

Tags: javascript

у меня есть массив. в нем каждый элемент - это объект с тремя свойствами. названия свойств у каждого элемента одинаковые. 
у меня есть переменная. я хочу убедиться, что в каждом объекте каждого элемента моего массива **определенное свойство** не равняется этой переменной. значения остальных двух свойств не важны (в данный момент)
пробовал сделать проверку через includes, но мой код пытался найти в массиве объект с единственным свойством (вместо необходимых трёх) и потому не работал (код ниже)

```
if(МАССИВ.includes({значение_той_самой_переменной_равной_свойство1})===false){
    МАССИВ.push({свойство1,свойство2,свойство3});    
}
```

код банально должен с помощью push добавлять в конец массива новый объект если в массиве уже нет схожего объекта с точно таким же значением "свойство1"
(ну а если есть, то через else просто работать с ним, но это к вопросу уже не относится)

Ниже оригинал кода
arr_bigram - массив
test - переменная в которой находится значение для проверки
i,j - обычные счетчики из форов находящихся на несколько уровней выше (выполняют роль 2 и 3 свойства каждого объекта)

```
if(arr_bigram.includes({test})===false){
   arr_bigram.push({test,i,j});    
}
else{
   for (let q in arr_bigram){
       if(test===arr_bigram[q].test){
           arr_bigram[q].i=i-arr_bigram[q].i;
           arr_bigram[q].j=j-arr_bigram[q].j;
        }              
    }
 }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85414/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Comment: @Igor, пожалуйста, старайтесь быть дружелюбнее к посетителям сайта) Не всегда все сразу вникают как составить идеальный вопрос. Порой на это уходят месяцы активного пользования сайтом)

Comment: @Grundy, как ты ухитряешься всё дубликатить??

Comment: @Qwertiy вопрос, скорее, как Вы ухитряетесь ответить на закрытый вопрос

Comment: @Igor, у меня вкладка была открыта давно, я про неё забыл))

Comment: @Igor, вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1971/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Так возникают мифы о секретных возможностях модераторов.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!array.some(x => x.prop3 === valueToExclude))
```